# Make cascading list mandatory on JIRA based on another cascading list

Tags: jira, behavior, scriptrunner-for-jira

I think this can be achieved with behaviors but I am struggling with the code.

I am trying to make "Cascading list 2" mandatory when an option is picked from "Cascading list 1"

Eg:

- On "Cascading list 1" if a user picks option "A" then they have to also fill out "Cascading list 2"
- If they pick option "B" on "Cascading list 1" then "Cascading list 2" is not required.

This is some of the code I was playing around with:

```
def fieldA = getFieldByName('BI Reporting & Analytics Request Categories') //this is cascading list 1

def fieldC = getFieldByName('Reporting') //this is the cascading list 2

def fieldAValuesThatTriggerFieldCRequired = ['Reporting'] //this is the option choosen in cascading list 1

def valueA = fieldA.value


def fieldCIsRequired = valueA in fieldAValuesThatTriggerFieldCRequired

fieldC.setRequired(fieldCIsRequired)
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

[Image on JIRA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z1DQ.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind clarify what you mean about cascading list? Jira has cascading field but looks not what you mean here.

Comment: Hi, I possibly did not explain it too well - I added an image to the original post if that will help?

Say for the list 1, if a user chooses the options "Reporting" then list 2 should be mandatory as well.

Comment: So they are actually independent from each other but you want one's value will affect two's behaviour. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, they are not cascading field.

The request here is that when field A has particular value saying 'aaa', then field B becomes required (mandatory).

This is a typical use case for Jira plugin Adaptavist ScriptRunner behaviours.

But Behaviours is only available for Jira server or data center version. It is not for Jira cloud.

If your Jira is server version, you can refer to below steps and scripts:

1. go to behaviours settings, if you don't have a behaviour item for
   your workflow, please create it. If behaviour has been created,
   click into action/edit.
2. choose the field A and add it.
3. click `Add server-side script`, you will see the black inline edit section.
4. add below code.

```
import com.onresolve.jira.groovy.user.FieldBehaviours
import com.onresolve.jira.groovy.user.FormField
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

@BaseScript FieldBehaviours fieldBehaviours

FormField field1 = getFieldById(getFieldChanged()) // we need to capture the change in field 1.
FormField pmAuthor = getFieldByName("field2")
if (field1.getValue()) { // to check if field1 has value as the action on field could be a deleting value operation.
    if (field2.getValue()=="A") {
        field2.setRequired(true)
    } else {
        field2.setRequired(false)
    }
} else { // if the value was deleted, then remove the requirement.
    field2.setRequired(false)
}
```